# Is there a way to use APIs build using Nodejs into Xamarin forms, for updating, writing and fetching datas from mongodb to app and vice-versa?

Tags: node.js, xamarin.forms

I am building a cross-platform application using xamarin forms and need some advice on how to perform write, read and updating datas from my xamarinform codes through Nodejs into mongo database. Code for c# to pass data read from the app entry to the nodejs api and finally into the database.

Comment: I have seen an article before whether it will help you or not ：https://strongloop.com/strongblog/nodejs-loopback-xamarin-sdk-sql-server/